# Translating "hint" in a mathematical context

Tags: traduction, anglais, choix-de-mot, mathématiques

J'ai un mot sur le bout de la langue, mais je n'arrive pas à le trouver. Je voudrais rendre en français le mot "hint" dans le contexte d'énoncés des exercices mathématiques. P. ex.

> ...Here are some hints on how to do basic math calculations.
>
> Prove the De Moivre's theorem. (Hint: use an inductive argument).

Est-ce conseil, consigne ou un autre mot ?

> ...Voici quelques conseils sur la façon de faire des calculs mathématiques de base.
>
> Démontrer le théorème de De Moivre. (Consigne : utiliser le raisonnement par récurrence).

Comment: "...Here are some hints on how to do basic math calculations." manque de contexte. Deuxième exemple : Une consigne serait un ordre.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On trouve fréquemment "indication" dans ce contexte.

Answer (score 4):

Je dirais Astuce ou Indice suivant le ton de l'énoncé.

Comment: 'Astuce' implique qu'on n'y aurait pas pensé spontanément. 'Indice' est plus neutre.